# How to run Jasmine on multiple pages?

Tags: jasmine

A lot of examples out there focus on writing tests and pretty much everything is closed in one single html file.
I'm more interested in how to actually run Jasmine within real-life app (which is not a SPA).

For the first test I included my `SpecRunner.html` at the very end of my app's framework:

```
include PATH_TOOLS.'/tests/jasmine/SpecRunner.html';
```

and this works, wherever I go in my app I have the test results at the bottom of the page. Obviously this kind of mixing test code with framework's code is not the cleanest approach - every time I push my commits to repository I'd have to remove this line.

On the other hand, If I open `SpecRunner.html` directly I cannot navigate to my app from there, unless it would be opened in iframe, but is it a common practice? I doubt. I know I can always run Jasmine in terminal, but I would prefer to see the results beside my app.

Perhaps I can somehow run Jasmine from command line and force it to open my app in a real browser, like Selenium does?

Comment: take a look at Karma

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I need, but I still [don't know how to run it with my whole app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40505024/how-to-include-php-file-to-run-test-in-karma-jasmine)