# How to include PHP file to run test in Karma/Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

The JS file I want to test is useless without PHP app on top of which it executes, because backend of my app generates all the DOM elements and data, which my JS app utilizes.

In other words, If I write in `my.conf.js`:

```
files: [
      'app.js',
      'spec/test.js'
      ],
```

`app.js` will throw tons of errors regarding not found elements, like tables, graph containers, etc.

Because of that I need to include my whole app to the test somehow. Perhaps by including my app's main `index.php`? Is it possible in Karma/Jasmine? Or do I rather set some kind of redirect?

Comment: if you definitely need DOM already in place with some content you can (and should) use [fixtures](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery)

Comment: so from what I understand these fixtures are some kind of mocked content I have to prepare? is there really no way to use real DOM content coming from my app? or at least to export it automatically to these fixtures somehow?

Comment: that's right, they are used to mock DOM content needed for your js to operate on. basically you can just copy-paste it from your backend's output html. but a better idea (at least for unit testing) would be to use some small fixtures for each testcase of each component. anyway, setting your front-end testing (and development) dependent on backend is something that one should rather avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @xmike is valid, but if you were to insist you can use [Karma's `proxies` configuration](https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html).